# Why is my Flicker API Search not working anymore?

Tags: android, json, flickr

I have a search query for flicker that was built using my android application. A few months earlier, I received images with it. Now I can't receive any images with it anymore. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The query is:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=mykey&lat=37.78680505813682&lon=-122.39814616422706&accuracy=11&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=date_taken,geo,url_h,views,tags

It should be giving me images of san francisco but the resuls is as follows:

[image]

I've exchanged my api key for "mykey".
I've checked my api key and it is still working with the getRecent method.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Came across your question while looking for the solution.   The same thing is happening for me when I make a call like: 
https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?lang=en-us&format=json&id=******&tagmode=any&tags=mytag

if i remove the tags= part it works fine, and if i change the format to one of the other options, it also works fine.  

I think this is a bug on flickr's end, but I haven't been able to track down any acknowledgement or official bug reports yet.

Comment: to add:  seems the format doesn't actually matter, just tags existing or not, and there is 100% photos with said tags.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Flickr Might have fixed this bug over the weekend!
per this thread in the API group:

https://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157721917411767/

If this doesn't fix yours, I would suggest contacting them through there!